# Images are broken / missing / not displaying in Google Groups posts (GSuite)

Tags: google-workspace

We are planning to use GSuite's Groups for our business to which we later plan to build front ends using Gsuite API to build helpdesks, public forums, etc but are having problems with broken links to inline images in posts to our groups.

It **seems that only the person who inserted the images into a private google group post can view** the images on the via the group's web interface, even using the same browser / machine for different accounts which are members of the same domain / different domain.

**Please advise any permissions to check** in the Gsuite groups settings page **or if there is any GSuite API I could use to try and troubleshoot** why the images are not downloading.

Related Google GSuite support forum post:

[Images are broken / missing / not displaying in Google Groups posts (GSuite)](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/JjhTXYI_oZE)

**User that created the post**:

[image: Example of working images]

**User that did not create the post**

[image: Example view of broken images]

Answer (score 0):

After reading assorted posts on Google Product Forums, I figured out that the "drag-drop" or select from computer method does not work. What you have to do instead is:

1. Be sure to remove/delete your previous attempted image from your new post. Even though you saw it upload and it appeared to work, once you posted the topic or message, you see the broken image icon.
2. Now go to Google Photos for that same Google Account.
3. Drag/drop or upload your image to Google Photos.
4. Now go back to Google Groups, click the image icon in the compose window, then this time when you get the popup window to choose a photo, select "Your Photos" from the left column menu. You should see the image that you uploaded using Google Photos.

[Image Uploader screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8eEP.png)

5. Select that image, then click SELECT action button. This time the image that gets inserted into the new post will display after you click POST.